# How to get the list of remaining interval after subtracting a interval from base time interval

Tags: java, jodatime

Is there any approach in `java` by using which I can list down the left over time intervals after removing a sub-time interval from the base time interval.

**Example:** consider a time interval of 0 to 24 hours is present and if I remove time from `10 AM` to `12AM`, then the left over time intervals should be `0-10` and `12-24`.

In this case, the base interval is 0-24 hrs.

Comment: Your question is not clear....Can you explain it

Comment: In Joda-Time, there is no special support so you have to write your own somehow lengthy solution based on the class `Interval`. My lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) has [built-in support](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/IntervalCollection.html#minus-net.time4j.range.ChronoInterval-) for several interval types - for example for `MomentInterval` or for `TimestampInterval` etc.

Comment: If you can, you should switch to the new Java Date and Time API (`java.time`), which supplants Joda Time.

Comment: @MCEmperor i explored java 8 date & time library but couldn't find any direct approach.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find method for this in Joda library nor in SDK.

Basically interval is defined as a start and end timestamp.
Method for substracting could have this logic:

Base interval (s1,e1)

Subsctracted interval (s2,e2)

If `s1<s2` and `e2<e1` then complement intervals are (s1, s2) and (e2, e1)

If `s2<s1` and `e2<e1` then complement is (e2, e1)

If `s1<s2` and `e1<e2` then complement is (s1, s2)

If base is inside substracted then complement is null

If no intersection result is base interval.

[image]

Comment: a) The OP wants Joda, see the tag b) Obviously the whole thing is not soooo simple: Instead of (e1, e2), the correct example would be (e2, e1). And if you still think it is so simple then why not presenting a complete solution in Joda?

Comment: @MenoHochschild Thank you for correction. If I make a typo, it does not mean anything. Feel free to answer question with your own library.